# Putting Values in Controls when dynamically creating a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been working on an issue for a while and I finally figured it out. I was trying to set a control when the Form is being initialize. I am thinking that the control's value isn't being set is because the control has been drawn yet (CORRECT ME IF I AM WRONG).

My partial form code

```
//in form 1    
....
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 form = new Form2();
                form.Owner = this;
                form.Show(this);
            }
....}

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        setData(); //Sets a datagridview's combobox column and databinds a datatable
        setGrid(); //Sets each row in the datagridview combobox's value to a string 
    }
    private void setData()
    {
        gvTest.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        string strConn = "server=10.253.3.185;database=petersun-test1;user id=ctore;password=cqi$$;connection timeout=30";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn);
        DataTable dit = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            string sql = "SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(COLUMN_NAME)) as ColumnName from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where Table_Name='coproc' order by ORDINAL_POSITION";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dit);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn dcDatabasefields = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            dcDatabasefields.DataPropertyName = "ColumnName";
            dcDatabasefields.HeaderText = "Database Field Name";
            dcDatabasefields.Name = "dbFields";
            dcDatabasefields.DisplayMember = "ColumnName";
            dcDatabasefields.ValueMember = "ColumnName";
            dcDatabasefields.Width = 200;
            BindingSource bsourceFields = new BindingSource();
            bsourceFields.DataSource = dit;
            dcDatabasefields.DataSource = bsourceFields;

            dcDatabasefields.DataSource = dit; // bsourceFields;
            gvTest.Columns.Add(dcDatabasefields);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("options");
        dt.Columns.Add(dc);
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["options"] = "A";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["options"] = "C";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["options"] = "D";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["options"] = "E";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        gvTest.DataSource = dt;
    }
private void setGrid()
{
 foreach(DataGridView Row in gvGrid.Rows)
 {
   Row.Cells[0].Value = "string";
  }
}
```

So what I think is happening is:
1. The component is getting initialized
2. Creates the datagridview with columns
3. Sets the column values
4. Draws the form

Is my thinking correct? My question is what form event should I set the control's value? I did some research and I am thinking on the PAINT event, but I am not sure either. Could someone explain the Form's life cycle in some detail or point me to somewhere.
Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to setting properties of the control with variables like height/width, or adding data to be displayed by the control?

Comment: Show us the code for setData and setGrid

Comment: added it to my question... just a simple loop

Comment: i am talking about variables to be displayed by the control like.. textbox1.text = "string";

Comment: This is not clear, why are you using databinding?

Comment: i am databinding the combobox column with data from a server

Comment: @user2252502 - ok here is one problem you have this :  `gvTest.Columns.Add(dcDatabasefields);` and this `gvTest.DataSource = dt;`.   You can't have both.  You databind or add them by hand, not both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added the coded into the Form_load and it added the values to the grid